# How to update object fields from another object using Modelmapper

Tags: java, object, copy, deep-copy, modelmapper

I am planning to write a method which use to update a `MyObject` object with not null fields of another `MyObject` object.

```
private void updateMyObject(MyObject sourceObject, MyObject destinationObject) {
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    mapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());
    mapper.map(sourceObject, destinationObject);
}

public class MyObject {
    long id;

    long durationInMilliSecounds;

    //...getters and setters 
}
```

In here `destinationObject` is not getting updated. Can anybody suggest the issue of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have previously used a `ModelMapper` version `0.6.5` and upgrading it to the `1.1.0` issue was fixed

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be missing some code. Perhaps the error is in that code. I am guessing that your model does not have both getters and setters, which is required by ModelMapper.

The following code works as expected:

```
public class modelMapperTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    mapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());

    MyModel sor = new MyModel(null, 5);
    MyModel des = new MyModel("yyy", 0);        

    System.out.println(des);
    mapper.map(sor, des);
    System.out.println(des);
}
```

with

```
public class MyModel {
    private String s;
    private int i;

public String getS() {
    return s;
}

public void setS(String s) {
    this.s = s;
}

public int getI() {
    return i;
}

public void setI(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public MyModel(String s, int i) {
    super();
    this.s = s;
    this.i = i;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyModel [s=" + s + ", i=" + i + "]";
}

}
```

Prints:

MyModel [s=yyy, i=0]

MyModel [s=yyy, i=5]

Comment: MyObject class has the getters and setters. I have update the question with that information

Comment: I don't see that the update. I am using ver. 1.1.0 are you? Please show the rest of the code and config.

Comment: I know this is old but do you know why if one of my objects has another object with a list of strings as a field with this [A, B, C] and if I try to merge it with another with that value as [A, C] I am getting [A, C, C] when I should get [A, C]